# How to shuffle a string of symbols (i.e. $, %, ^)

Tags: python

I need to create a string of `" % % % "`. The spaces included too. And I need the %'s to be randomly placed each time I run the code. So it can be `"%  % % "`, `"  %%  %%"` etc. I've tried using `random.shuffle(x)` but it comes up with the error message `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Is there any other way to have the string be shuffled? Or what can I do to fix the error message?

Comment: Please share the code, so that we can help you fix it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @jakekimds, random.shuffle modifies its mutable-string argument in-place and returns None, so your solution can't possibly work.

Comment: @AlexMartelli oops. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
import random

# Create a list of characters, in this case 5 % and 5 spaces
l = ['%'] * 5 + [' '] * 5

# Shuffle it
random.shuffle(l)

# Create a string from the shuffled list
s = ''.join(l)
print(s)
```

Alternatively, you could initialize `l` with the results of calling `list()` on an input string:

```
l = list(" % % % ")
```

This would just be like `l = ['%'] * 3 + [' '] * 4`

With the rest of the code the same, you'd get what you're looking for.